# BMI calculation C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I need some help with calculating the BMI. I have read in data from a file and populated 2 arrays that contain the weight and height of people. I am creating a 3rd array that contains the BMI of those people. I know that the BMI is bmi = weight / (Height * Height); The problem I am having though, is how do I calculate the BMI when the data I need to calculate with is stored into arrays. I was thinking about looping through each array (height and weight) and calculating the BMI in that loop by each index of the array. Both arrays are the same size too and are of double data type. Can someone tell me if this is the best way to go about this?

Comment: That sounds like a fine solution. I mean, how else would you propose to do it?

Comment: yes, that is the best way to do that.. or else you could store the height and weight as vector<pair<double, double>>. By this way, you will loop only through one array.

Comment: @alrikai I was thinking about using a 3 layer nested loop, one that loops through all 3 arrays and increments up until sizeof(bmi[], height[], and weight[])?

Comment: @user1207457 does each index represent a distinct person? e.g. bmi[i] = weight[i]/(height[i]*height[i])?

Comment: @alrikai well, it would be 3 different index, (i,j,k) and 3 loops, (each iterating through a different array), so that way i can store the new values from the bmi formula into the new bmi array.

Comment: Or rather, what I was asking was whether the indices are aligned, such that if your height and weight arrays have n-elements, you'll be finding n-BMI values, where the ith element in height and width correspond to the ith BMI value. If so, then having 3 different loops is extraneous and the calculation can be done in 1 loop with 3 array accesses.

Comment: @alrikai yes, all three arrays would be the same size and have the same n elements. How could this be done with one loop? Can you provide a sample example in the answers section below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In regards to your comment in the question, you don't have to do 3 nested loops, as the indices align across your three arrays (height, weight, and BMI). Just for the sake of example, we have your 2 input arrays referenced in your question, height and weight as being of length n.

```
const int n = 10;
double height [n];
double weight [n];
//read from array, populate arrays height and width
//...

//have 1 output BMI value per input value
double BMI [n];

//calculate the BMI values based on the heights and widths
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    BMI[i] = height[i] / (weight[i]*weight[i]);
}
```

Hopefully I understood what you were asking correctly

Comment: Ok, I tired that, I am getting the same weird negative number as all of the people's BMI. It says "-1.08038e-058"

Comment: that sounds like you're using uninitialized data. Are you reading in your heights and weights properly? Try debugging your code or printing your values read from your data file(s) to make sure you are getting the data correctly

Comment: I am, but I cannot figure out for the life of me why its the same number for each person, and weight exponential negative number...

Comment: maybe you can post your code to see if it's a coding problem, and/or try running on a small test case (e.g. a couple of elements) with inputs that you have confirmed to be correct.

Comment: @user1207457 How do you *know* you're reading the input correctly? Remember, *knowing* you are reading the input correctly isn't the same as *believing* you're reading the input correctly. And even if you read it correctly, do you *store* it correctly?

Comment: is this legal: for (int i=0;i<fun && bmi;i++) with fun being a function and bmi being an array? fun is a function that reads in the height and weight from the file. bmi is the array that stores the calculated bmi's.

Comment: @user1207457 doesn't sound like that'll do what you expect it to do... Are you using that loop to read your data?

Comment: @alrikai no I am using it to output my data. I have a cout that is a part of that loop that outputs the weight and height but so I can output the BMI as well, I incorporated the && bmi

Comment: That won't work as you hoped then. fun is a function pointer, and bmi in that context is a pointer to the 0th element of your BMI array. Why not just loop over the length of your data, you don't need (or want) the "&& bmi" part.

Comment: (whistle) Division by zero. (whistle)